# Python fixed terminal size

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

So I am trying to make a simple database program that prints its cells and columns into stdout one thing that is messing up my result is if I change the window size, is there a way to make it go to a fixed size?

Comment: You may try to use the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html) library, which does have some resizing functionality, but it's not really portable[doesn't work on windows I believe].

Comment: Do you want your table at a fixed size? If so [PrettyTable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) might help. Otherwise I imagine there other terminals you can use and set their default size to something else